# Why does heap allocated data sparsely?

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory

Why heap memory is allocated data sparsely.
for example.. in c++ vector can control own size, so To occupy own space to expand size,
heap memory is allocated data sparsely?
I can't understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data allocation mainly depends on the the kernel code.
In a perfect world you could always have allocation made contiguously but in reality at the first deallocation you will have "holes" in your memory.
For this reason the kernel usually doesn't really try to keep everything contiguous across multiple allocations as it isn't really useful and would slow down the process.